# How do I add a 2nd modal to my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I didn't explain my problem in my last post.

So I want to add a second modal to my html page so if you click on "Button 1" it would open "Modal 1" and if you click "button 2" it will open "Modal 2" however "button 3" "button 4" "button 5" and "button 6" to open "modal 2". When i created the second modal and set the javascript below. It will keep opening Modal 2 on both buttons and not modal 1 on button 1.

**Also note, the ID of the first button "free"**

**Also note, the ID of the second button "oneday"**

```html
<script>
// Get the modal1
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("free");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
// Get the modal2
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("oneday");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Both buttons keep opening "Modal2" when the button 1 is set for "Modal1"
HTML Below

**Button 1**

```html
<!-- service item -->
<div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="500ms">
  <div class="service-item">
    <div class="service-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o  fa-2x"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="service-desc">
      <button id="free">
        <h3>5 Day Free Trial</h3> 
      </button>
      <b><p>So you can get a taste of the action for free, we will give new users a 5 day trial to see how they like our bot before they buy!</p> </b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end service item -->
```

**Button 2**

```
<!-- service item -->
<div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="500ms">
  <div class="service-item">
    <div class="service-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="service-desc">
      <button id="oneday">
        <h3>1 Day</h3> 
      </button>
      <b><p>$0.74  &nbsp;&nbsp;-24 Hours </p> </b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end service item -->
```

***And the Modals are here***

**Modal1**

```html
<!-- Modal1 -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <form name="getinfo" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-style-8">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <label for="msg">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Username:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="user" name="username">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Confirm Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="cpassword">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">3 Hashtags:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="tags" name="hashtags">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Modal2**

```html
<!-- Modal2 content -->
<div class="modal-content">

  <form name="getinfo2" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-style-8">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <label for="msg">Example:</label>
      <input type="email" id="e1" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example2:</label>
      <br>
      <input id="e2" name="username">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example3:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="e3" name="password">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example4:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="e4" name="cpassword">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example5:</label>
      <br>
      <input id="e5" name="hashtags">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

So i'm asking how do I get modal1 to work only with button1 and modal2 to work with buttons 2,3,4,5 and 6 that i will create later.

Comment: Seems you are using bootsrap css , are you not using bootsrap.js ? If you are you don't need to manually hide/show the modals and can use their api for them

Comment: I am using bootsrap.js however i'm new to html coding so i don't know to much about it

Comment: Use different variables to store refrence to the modals.

Comment: Have you read through their API docs? And tried their examples? Can open a modal 2 ways...using javascript or by simply putting data attributes on the triggering element(s)

Comment: As @A.J mentioned, you are assigning both modals and buttons to `modal` and `btn`, respectively. Give those variables different names and adjust your events accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one modal -- it's just a DIV structure, nothing magic *(the only `magic` is making it appear/disappear - and bootstrap does that trick).* When needed, grab the desired content from where you have it stored, stick it into the modal's `.modal-body` div, and let bootstrap display it.

Here's how.

(1) Store the ***content*** for each modal in hidden DIVs elsewhere in the document.

(2) Give each button an ID with a unique number you can isolate, and give each "hidden modal content div" a name ending with the same number. For example, button "#btn_2" will match with hidden div "#mdl2", which contains the content you want for button #btn_2.

(3) Use javascript (you are using Bootstrap, which uses jQuery, so why not use jQuery) to swap in the correct content. When you click the button, isolate the number 2 (`var buttNum = this.id.split('_')[1];` - try it) and use that to grab the html from the `#mdl2` div (`var content = $('#mdl'+buttNum).html()`)

(4) Let Bootstrap take care of opening/closing the modal.

Example:

```js
$('[id^=btn_]').click(function(){
  var buttNum = this.id.split('_')[1];
  //alert(buttNum);
  var content = $('#mdl'+buttNum).html();
  $('#myModal1 .modal-body').html(content);
});
```

```css
#mdl1, #mdl2, #mdl3{display:none;} /*  Hide the divs containing modal content */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Re-Using the Same Modal</h3>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button id="btn_1" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal One</button>
  <button id="btn_2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal Two</button>
  <button id="btn_3" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Ogden Nash Poem</button>

  <!-- Re-Usable Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Stick your modal content in hidden divs at bottom of the page -->
  <div id="mdl1">
    <div>Click outside modal to close modal</div>
    <form name="getinfo" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-style-8">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <label for="msg">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Username:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="user" name="username">

      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">Confirm Password:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="cpassword">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="msg">3 Hashtags:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="tags" name="hashtags">   
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="mdl2">
      <div>Click outside modal to close modal</div>
      <h1>Image of an Animal</h1>
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" />
  </div><!-- #mdl2 -->
  <div id="mdl3">
      <div>Click outside modal to close modal</div>
      <h1>Poem by Ogden Nash</h1>
      <div style="font-size:1.4rem;">
  <div>The hands of the clock were reaching high</div>
  <div>In an old midtown hotel;</div>
  <div>I name no name, but its sordid fame</div>
  <div>Is table talk in hell.</div>
  <div>I name no name, but hell's own flame</div>
  <div>Illumes the lobby garish,</div>
  <div>A gilded snare just off Times Square</div>
  <div>For the maidens of the parish.</div>

  <div>The revolving door swept the grimy floor</div>
  <div>Like a crinoline grotesque,</div>
  <div>And a lowly bum from an ancient slum</div>
  <div>Crept furtively past the desk.</div>
  <div>His footsteps sift into the lift</div>
  <div>As a knife in the sheath is slipped,</div>
  <div>Stealthy and swift into the lift</div>
  <div>As a vampire into a crypt.</div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- #mdl3 -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write javascript to hide or show modals use the right data-target and data-toggle in the button tag as shown below and bootstrap will automatically do the rest.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Large Modal</button>`

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Large Modal</button>`

Set `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target='<your-modal-id>'` inside the button tag as shown above.

To show two modal for two buttons just add the id of new modal in the `data-target='<your-modal-id>'` attribute in the new button.

Now create multiple modals and give each of them a different `<your_modal_id>`

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="<your_modal_id>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">

            YOUR MODAL HTML CODE

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATED: ADDING CLOSE BUTTON TO CLOSE THE MODAL BY BOOTSTRAP**

Replace `<span class="close">&times;</span>` in your modal with

`<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`

it will close the modal automatically on clicking close button on the modal.

Here is an example of how to use two modals

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Large Modal</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Large Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal 1 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          
      <form name="getinfo" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-style-8">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <label for="msg">E-mail:</label>
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="msg">Username:</label>
         <br>
         <input id="user" name="username">
        
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="msg">Password:</label>
         <br>
          <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        </div>
        <div>
              <label for="msg">Confirm Password:</label>
              <br>
              <input type="password" id="pass" name="cpassword">
        </div>
        <div>
              <label for="msg">3 Hashtags:</label>
              <br>
              <input id="tags" name="hashtags">   
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
          </div>
     </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Modal 2-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form name="getinfo2" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="php/gmail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-style-8">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <label for="msg">Example:</label>
      <input type="email" id="e1" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example2:</label>
      <br>
      <input id="e2" name="username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example3:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="e3" name="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example4:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="e4" name="cpassword">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="msg">Example5:</label>
      <br>
      <input id="e5" name="hashtags">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Nadir! However now that I that implemented into my real purchase.html. It opens the modal right for both buttons. But when it closes and reopens. It wont show up the second time

Comment: `span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}`

Have you removed your javascript that existed earlier

The code above hides the modal, you don't need any javascript to hide or show bootstrap will do it for you.

Comment: See my updated answer and replace `<span class="close">&times;</span>` in your modal with
      `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>` it will close the modal automatically on clicking close button on the modal