# How can I create a dialog box with iframe and multiple tabs in it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, dialog

When I click on a tab, I want to open a dialog box that contains multiple tabs that link to other dialog boxes. These other dialog boxes will contain iframes.

Please take a look of the following working website I referencing from a online store:
[Link](http://www.brooksbrothers.com/Mini-BB%231-Rep-Tie/MA02077,default,pd.html)

[image]

Comment: you need javascript to update the src of your iframe. (i did not follw the link provided, relevant code showing your issue should stand here, not else where, where it can be not avalaible at anytime)

Comment: Is that for the content in different iframe, I have to create a separate .html files for them?

Comment: ＠gibberish Thank you for your clarification... I misunderstand that it should be done by html and css.... Would you please kindly provide me an example about it? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: ＠gibberish Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I can't do the full example you describe in the question - I would end up doing your entire project. But here is the part that you might be most stuck on.

You can do an awful lot with jQuery and jQueryUI. There is very little code in this example, and look what it does.

You will want to explore the jQueryUI Dialog and Tab "widgets" *(Their term - I would call them plugins or add-ons or something else)* and especially the "API" for each widget. The API tells you how to control every aspect of the widget and provides many examples. For instance - how did I know to use `autoOpen:false` in the dialog definition? The API and the examples.

jQuery and jQueryYI are a great place to start.

Very important: Note that at the top of the HTML with include three libraries:

- The CSS for jQueryUI
- jQuery library
- jQueryUI library (must follow the jQuery library or it wont work)

```js
$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); //makes the tabs work (inside Dlg)

$( "#myDlg" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Just a Q&D example - jQUI is super configurable',
  width: 800,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true
});

$('#btnOpenSesame').click(function(){
  $('#myDlg').dialog('open');
});
```

```css
iframe{min-width:1000px;min-height:500px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Above order of libraries is important -->

<h4>This example displays best in Full Screen (look for that link at top right of running example)</h4>

<button id="btnOpenSesame">Open Dialog</button>

<div id="myDlg">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Wikipedia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">ZeroHedge</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Breitbart</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <iframe src="http://wikipedia.org"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <iframe src="http://zerohedge.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <iframe src="http://breitbart.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #tabs -->
</div><!-- #myDlg -->
```

---

You should also review the following tutorials (if you are not already fully comfortable):

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

---

Update: To select the active tab after a button press, use

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Example:

```js
$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); //makes the tabs work (inside Dlg)

$( "#myDlg" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Just a Q&D example - jQUI is super configurable',
  width: 800,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true
});

$('#btnOpenSesame').click(function(){
  $('#myDlg').dialog('open');
});

$('#btnTab0').click(function(){
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
});
$('#btnTab1').click(function(){
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
});
$('#btnTab2').click(function(){
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
});
```

```css
iframe{min-width:1000px;min-height:500px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Above order of libraries is important -->

<h4>This example displays best in Full Screen (look for that link at top right of running example)</h4>

<button id="btnOpenSesame">Open Dialog</button>

<div id="myDlg">
  <div>
    <button id="btnTab0">Open Tab 0</button>
    <button id="btnTab1">Open Tab 1</button>
    <button id="btnTab2">Open Tab 2</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Wikipedia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">ZeroHedge</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Breitbart</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <iframe src="http://wikipedia.org"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <iframe src="http://zerohedge.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <iframe src="http://breitbart.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #tabs -->
</div><!-- #myDlg -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your example. I think it is useful! One question is that instead of your example, I am using an anchor inside a <li> instead of <button>, so do I need to add anything on the <a href> so as to make it working? Because I have tried your code and it is not working to open the dialog box. Thank you so much for your time again!

Comment: And I found that for the libraries import, I have got a few similar files in my project originally, like "jqueru.ui.all.css", "jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js"... They look similar but did they actually overlapping with each other? As after I have added the libraries, some of my previous made dialog boxes are no longer hidden their content anymore and the dialog box in your example cannot be opened... Moreover, will there have any versions issues on the libraries?

Comment: I can finally make the dialog appears now, many thanks! But I dun know why the three iframe will always appear on the same tab page and I cannot set the tab which is to be active on a certain click...

Comment: jQuery and jQueryUI work together, as you realized. And yes, you are right, it used to be important to know which jQueryUI version matches with which version of jQuery, but if you are using jQuery version 7.0+ you will be fine. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history) and also [Note that jQuery versions 2.x and 3.x do not support MSIE < 9](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-1-11-4-compatible-with-jquery-2-1-4)

Comment: Thanks! Let me check again if there is any problem with the version as I believe I am using 7.0+... btw, may I ask the usage of #yourDlgContent{display:none;} ??

Comment: Sorry, that was left behind from an idea I abandoned. I was going to demo how to swap data in/out of the dialog, and I was storing the `tabs` div structure in that hidden div called `yourDlgContent`, but I found it too much for this answer. If you are interested, [here it is in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41413355/1447509)