# Easiest way to use a div as a modal dialog with jQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to show the contents of a div as a modal dialog using jQuery.

Is there any way to do it without using Bootstrap or anything else...?

I want to personalize my modal dialog, my own way, via CSS.

Please show me a way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "roll-your-own" modal dialog, all you need are two divs:

1. The overlay - sits on top of your page content (we use `z-index` to accomplish this)
2. The dialog - sits on top of the overlay div

#### UPDATE 2023: Here's how I do it now:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('#myButt').addEventListener('click', () => {
  $('#modal').style.display = 'flex';
});

$('#modal_inner').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.id === 'closeX'){
     $('#modal').style.display = 'none';
  }
});

$('#yourButt').addEventListener('click', () => {
  $('#modal_inner').innerHTML = '<div id="closeX"> X </div><h2>A Different Quote</h2><p>Yesterday it was so hot that I saw two trees fighting over a dog.</p>';
});
```

```css
.flex-center-center{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;}
.flex-column {flex-direction:column;}
.pos-abs-full{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:99.5vw;height:100vh}

*{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:'Segoe UI Light', Arial, Helvetica;}
#modal{background:#000000cc;display:none;}
  #modal_inner{width:60vw;padding:0 20px 20px; color:darkcyan;background:#fff;border:1px solid #999; }
     #closeX{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;padding:2px 8px;color:darkcyan;}
     #closeX:hover{color:lawngreen;cursor:pointer;}
     
span{color:dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<h1>Pure JavaScript (Full Page) Example</h1>
<p>This is an example of a modal dialog, and of how easy it is to change the content.</p>
<p>This new example is pure javascript - no jQuery</p>
<p>The $ <span>looks like</span> jQuery, but it is just a pure-javascript alias for <span>querySelector()</span>.</p>
<button id="myButt">Click for Modal</button>

<div id="modal" class="pos-abs-full flex-center-center">
   <div id="modal_inner" class="flex-center-center flex-column">
      <div id="closeX"> X </div>
      <h2>This is the Modal content</h2>
      <div>You can tell a genius by this sign: that all the dunces are in a confederacy against him.</div>
      <p>Bertie! Get a haircut! You look like a chrysanthemum.</p>
      <button id="yourButt">Switch Content</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Original

Here is a basic code example.

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('#myOverlay').show();
    $('#myModal').show();
});

$('#shutme, #myOverlay').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').hide();
    $('#myOverlay').hide();
});
```

```css
#content{background:wheat;}
#myOverlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:black;opacity:0.7;display:none;z-index:1;}
#myModal{position:fixed;top:10%;left:10%;border:3px solid darkcyan;display:none;z-index:2;}
#shutme{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutt">Show Modal</button>
<div id="myOverlay"></div>
<div id="myModal">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/450/325" />
    <input type="button" id="shutme" value="Close" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. This is a bunch of content. 
</div>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/07bvb5Lz/)</kbd>

---

Important Notes:

1. `z-index` doesn't work on elements that are using the ***default*** CSS position value (`position:static`). If you don't need the element set to either `absolute` or `fixed`, then set it to `position:relative` (which is virtually the same as the default `static` value, but also supports `z-index`).
2. `position` is again important for the HTML structure of the dialog box itself. Again, change it from the default value of `position:static`. A position value of `fixed` will place it at a fixed location on the ***screen***, whereas `absolute` will allow you to position it anywhere within the first parent element that does not have a `position` value of `static` (you can see that the pesky `position:static` value is problematic - it's a wonder why it was chosen to be the default.
3. The overlay div is configured, using z-index, to sit on top of the webpage. We do this for two reasons: (1) to nicely frame the dialog box, visually; and (2) to prevent the user from interacting with the page until the dialog box is closed. *(Remember: `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`)* A nice effect is to make this div semi-transparent, using the `opacity` CSS property.
4. The dialog div is configured, using z-index, to sit on top of the overlay. Do not put the dialog div inside the overlay div. You can do this, but it is a little  more difficult - do it this way first, then experiment with other possibilities.
5. It's convenient to place the overlay and dialog div structures either at the very top of the body, or at the very bottom. Do NOT place them within containers. If you are using Bootstrap, you ***can*** use this method but you don't need to since [Bootstrap has its own modal dialog structure](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp) that makes it a little easier to configure a super-cool modal dialog. If you look at their HTML closely, you'll see it's really exactly the same concept as we are using here - it just does more.
6. You do not need a separate modal for each message. It's pretty simple to swap information in and out of the modal dialog structure. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413355/1447509) for more ideas and demos.

In fact, this is a key idea so here is another example that shows how simple it is to do:

```js
$('[id^=mybutt]').click(function(){
    //above selector traps clicks on els where: id "starts with" mybutt
    let btnID = $(this).attr('id');
    let mdlNo = btnID.split('_')[1];
    $('#content_num').val(mdlNo); //Store so can put the data back when done
    //below line MOVES data from numbered storage div into the modal for display
    $('#content_mdl' + mdlNo + ' .mdl_content').appendTo( $('#myMdlInner') );
    $('#myOverlay').show();
    $('#myModal').show();
});

$('#shutme, #myOverlay').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').hide();
    $('#myOverlay').hide();
    let mdlNo = $('#content_num').val(); //get the stored mdl_data number
    //below line MOVES the dialog contents back to the appropriate storage div
    $('#myMdlInner .mdl_content').appendTo( $('#content_mdl' + mdlNo) );
});
```

```css
#myOverlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:black;opacity:0.7;display:none;z-index:1;}

#myModal{position:fixed;top:10%;left:10%;width:70%;height:60%;border:3px solid darkcyan;overflow:hidden;display:none;z-index:2;}
  .mdl_content{height:100%;width:100%;background:white;}

#shutme{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:20px;}

.flex-parent{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;}
.mdl_data{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This demo re-uses one modal dialog for multiple content</h1>
<div id="myOverlay"></div>
<div id="myModal">
    <div id="myMdlInner"></div>
    <input type="button" id="shutme" value="Close" />
    <input type="hidden" id="content_num" />
</div>

<!-- Hidden divs containing content for the modal dialog -->
<div id="content_mdl1" class="mdl_data">
  <div class="mdl_content">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/450/325" />
  </div><!-- .mdl_content -->
</div><!-- #content_mdl1 -->

<div id="content_mdl2" class="mdl_data">
  <div class="mdl_content">
    <div class="flex-parent">
        <div class="fleft">Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .md2_content -->
</div><!-- #content_mdl2 -->

<button id="mybutt_1">Show Modal 1</button>
<button id="mybutt_2">Show Modal 2</button>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pwcmtoaz/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer....But I think it doesn't work after running snippet.

Comment: There is a "show modal" button in the snippet at top left - did you click that? What happened? FWIW, it does work on my side... Keen to know...

Comment: after clicking on the Show Modal button , it just shows me a close button and just this

Comment: Try [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07bvb5Lz/) demo - sometimes the StackSnippets environment doesn't work perfectly.