# Showing the modal by not altering the opacity of each element in the body

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a modal using vanilla javascript. Here is what I have done:

```js
let modal = document.createElement("div");
modal.id = "translation-loader";
modal.style.paddingRight = "15px";
modal.style.display = "block";
modal.style.overflowX = "hidden";
modal.style.overflowY = "auto";
modal.style.zIndex = "1072";
modal.style.position = "fixed";
modal.style.top = 0;
modal.style.left = 0;
modal.style.width = "100%";
modal.style.height = "100%";
modal.style.outline = 0
modal.classList.add("animated","fadeInDown")

let modalDialog = document.createElement("div");
modalDialog.style.maxWidth = "500px";
modalDialog.style.margin = "1.75rem auto";
modalDialog.style.position = "relative";
modalDialog.style.width = "auto";
modalDialog.style.transition = "transform .3s ease-out,-webkit-transform .3s ease-out";
modalDialog.style.pointerEvents = "none";
modalDialog.style.minHeight = "calc(100% - 3.5rem)";

modal.append(modalDialog);

let modalContent = document.createElement("div");
modalContent.style.position = "relative";
modalContent.style.display = "flex";
modalContent.style.flexDirection = "column";
modalContent.style.width = "100%";
modalContent.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
modalContent.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
modalContent.style.backgroundClip = "padding-box";
modalContent.style.border = "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2)";
modalContent.style.borderRadius = ".3rem";
modalContent.style.outline = 0;
modalDialog.append(modalContent);

let modalHeader = document.createElement("div");
modalHeader.style.display = "flex";
modalHeader.style.alignItems = "flex-Start";
modalHeader.style.justifyContent = "space-between";
modalHeader.style.padding = "1rem 1rem";
modalHeader.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #dee2e6";
modalHeader.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalHeader.style.borderTopRightRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
const modalHeaderElement = document.createElement("h5");
modalHeaderElement.innerText = "Translation In Progress";
modalHeaderElement.style.fontSize = "1.25rem";
modalHeaderElement.style.fontWeight = "500";
modalHeaderElement.style.marginTop = 0;
modalHeaderElement.style.marginBottom = 0;
modalHeader.append(modalHeaderElement);
modalContent.append(modalHeader);


let modalBody = document.createElement("div");
modalBody.style.position = "relative";
modalBody.style.flex = "1 1 auto";
modalBody.style.padding = "1rem";
modalBody.innerText = "Body";
modalContent.append(modalBody);


let modalFooter = document.createElement("div");
modalFooter.style.display = "flex";
modalFooter.style.flexWrap = "flex-wrap";
modalFooter.style.alignItems = "center";
modalFooter.style.justifyContent = "flex-end";
modalFooter.style.padding = "0.75rem";
modalFooter.style.borderTop = "1px solid #dee2e6";
modalFooter.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalFooter.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalFooter.innerText = "Footer"
modalContent.append(modalFooter);

document.body.append(modal);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, (child) => {
 if(child.id !== "translation-loader") {
   child.style.opacity = 0.1
  }
  console.log(child.id);
});
```

```html
<p>
This is a sample text..What'sup
<a href="#">click here</a>
</p>
```

As you could see, that to display the modal, I am changing the opacity of all elements except the modal to `0.1`. I think this is the incorrect way of showing the modal.  The reason is, I just cannot change the opacity of all other elements back to `1` when the modal hides. This could alter the original (default) opacity of an element.

What is the better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to make an `overlay` behind your `modal` and make its `opacity` using `background`.

In your case you can do that by

```
#translation-loader {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

**Second Approach using `pseudo` element**

```js
let modal = document.createElement("div");
modal.id = "translation-loader";
modal.style.paddingRight = "15px";
modal.style.display = "block";
modal.style.overflowX = "hidden";
modal.style.overflowY = "auto";
modal.style.zIndex = "1072";
modal.style.position = "fixed";
modal.style.top = 0;
modal.style.left = 0;
modal.style.width = "100%";
modal.style.height = "100%";
modal.style.outline = 0
modal.classList.add("animated","fadeInDown")

let modalDialog = document.createElement("div");
modalDialog.style.maxWidth = "500px";
modalDialog.style.margin = "1.75rem auto";
modalDialog.style.position = "relative";
modalDialog.style.width = "auto";
modalDialog.style.transition = "transform .3s ease-out,-webkit-transform .3s ease-out";
modalDialog.style.pointerEvents = "none";
modalDialog.style.minHeight = "calc(100% - 3.5rem)";

modal.append(modalDialog);

let modalContent = document.createElement("div");
modalContent.style.position = "relative";
modalContent.style.display = "flex";
modalContent.style.flexDirection = "column";
modalContent.style.width = "100%";
modalContent.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
modalContent.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
modalContent.style.backgroundClip = "padding-box";
modalContent.style.border = "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2)";
modalContent.style.borderRadius = ".3rem";
modalContent.style.outline = 0;
modalDialog.append(modalContent);

let modalHeader = document.createElement("div");
modalHeader.style.display = "flex";
modalHeader.style.alignItems = "flex-Start";
modalHeader.style.justifyContent = "space-between";
modalHeader.style.padding = "1rem 1rem";
modalHeader.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #dee2e6";
modalHeader.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalHeader.style.borderTopRightRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
const modalHeaderElement = document.createElement("h5");
modalHeaderElement.innerText = "Translation In Progress";
modalHeaderElement.style.fontSize = "1.25rem";
modalHeaderElement.style.fontWeight = "500";
modalHeaderElement.style.marginTop = 0;
modalHeaderElement.style.marginBottom = 0;
modalHeader.append(modalHeaderElement);
modalContent.append(modalHeader);


let modalBody = document.createElement("div");
modalBody.style.position = "relative";
modalBody.style.flex = "1 1 auto";
modalBody.style.padding = "1rem";
modalBody.innerText = "Body";
modalContent.append(modalBody);


let modalFooter = document.createElement("div");
modalFooter.style.display = "flex";
modalFooter.style.flexWrap = "flex-wrap";
modalFooter.style.alignItems = "center";
modalFooter.style.justifyContent = "flex-end";
modalFooter.style.padding = "0.75rem";
modalFooter.style.borderTop = "1px solid #dee2e6";
modalFooter.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalFooter.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "calc(.3rem - 1px)";
modalFooter.innerText = "Footer"
modalContent.append(modalFooter);

document.body.append(modal);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, (child) => {
 if(child.id !== "translation-loader") {
   child.style.opacity = 0.1
  }
  console.log(child.id);
});
```

```css
#translation-loader {
    position: relative;
}
#translation-loader::before {
    content: '';
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
This is a sample text..What'sup
<a href="#">click here</a>
</p>
```

> NOTE: You can change the opacity as per requirement.

Comment: But this does not work for a website like https://www.espncricinfo.com/. If you try the developer console and try to add a modal, you will see that it just does not appear for anyone to see.

Comment: Sorry @Amanda i didn't get your point . Can you explain a little bit more. As far as i know most of the modals use the background overlay either to prevent click functions or making opacity, You can have examples of bootstrap modal, angular material popup dialog and much more.

Comment: If you open espncricinfo.com and try running the javascript on the console, you will see that the modal is not viewable. I cannot understand the reason for this.

Comment: Its simple @Amanda You can inspect and see id `global-viewport` which act as background overlay with `opacity:0.1`, the difference is cricinfo create a separate div behind its modal and set its opacity while we do that by create background color on parent of modal. both are different way of achieving same goal. You can use pseudo `::before` if you want to do that by opacity. Need more explain i can update my answer.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could update your answer w.r.t to an example that works anywhere, anytime. https://www.espncricinfo.com/ was one website where I could not make the above example work.

Comment: @Amanda Just clear me one thing you want to give opacity to one element which cover body on modal open am i right? Just like cricinfo

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to display the modal so that, it is the only thing visible for some time.

Comment: @Amanda I update my answer hope this is what you want! Do let me know if you still have problem

Comment: It still does not work. I incorporated your changes into https://jsfiddle.net/k185sdzq/ and ran the same code by opening espncricinfo.com and pasting the entire javascript on the console. But the modal is not visible. I specifically want the modal to be visible for espncricinfo.com . Also making its position as relative pushes at the bottom of the webpage, which I do not want. I specifically want it be at the top (or center)

Comment: @Amanda I'll look into it what actually the problem is then will get back to you...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. You are doing a lot of styling in javascript. It is *much* more efficient to use classes. In fact, you already are doing this:

   `modal.classList.add("animated","fadeInDown")`

All of your styling should be via adding classes. Remove all `modal.style`, `modalDialog.style` and `modalContent.style` - just add classes and move the styling into the class *(`<style></style>` block or external stylesheet)*.

2. To show/hide the modal, use `style.display = none` and `style.display = block`. No need to use opacity.  If you want a fadeIn / fadeOut effect, there are many tutorials easily googleable. Here's one:

https://chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/

Note that the fade effect is just applied to the outermost div, the `modal` div. Everything inside that will also fade as that div fades in/out.

Here is a simple example of rolling your own modal dialog:

[Easiest way to use div as a modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796556/easiest-way-to-use-a-div-as-a-modal-dialog-with-jquery/56796636#56796636)