# How can I pop up small-sized window form when I click a photo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="featured-item">
                <img src="assets/images/preparing.jpg" alt=""  onclick="window.open('buy_form.html', '_blank');" />
                <h4>itemName</h4>
               
              </div>
```

I want to pop up a small window form(looks like a bill) but the code above show full-sized window not a small size. I tried to put elements about height and width next to the '_blank', but it doesn't work.

So I tried CSS,

```
body{
width: 400px;
height: 600px;
```

}

But it just resize the content of popup form.

I want to show small window through modifying the first code. (Other ways are okay. I appreciate all helps for this question.)

Answer (score 2):

`window.open` has some params:

```
window.open(buy_form.html,"NewWindow","width=420,height=290,status=yes,resizable=yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but you might also want to know about popping up a lightbox or a modal dialog, overtop the other content.

Here are examples that shows how.

[Easiest way to use a div as a modal dialog with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796556/easiest-way-to-use-a-div-as-a-modal-dialog-with-jquery/56796636#56796636)

[Insert data into a modal dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63760033/1447509)