# How do I add a modal made with html/css to my bootstrap website?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a modal inside my bootstrap website but for some reason it is not working.

So, it is is supposed to open whenever the user presses a button.

It was working on another html/css file, but once I added it to this bootstrap one, it stopped working.

Here is my modals html code, from index.html (bootstrap):

```
<!-- Modal  -->
  <div id="myModal">
    <div class="container" id="modalContainer">
    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
    <form action="#">
    <h1>MMT University</h1>
    <span>Se registre para começar</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
    <button name="submit">Registrar</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
    <form action="#">
    <h1>Acessar</h1>
    
    <span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
    <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
    <button>Acessar</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
      <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
      <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
      <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
      <h1>MMT University!</h1>
      <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
      <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="modal.js"></script>

  <main id="main">



    <!-- Modal -->
```

Button to open modal

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Open modal
              </button>
```

Modal.css

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------
# Modal 
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.wrapper .left{
  background: #313840;
}

.wrapper .left h3{
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper .left img{
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
}

.wrapper .right{
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper .right .tabs ul{
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .right .tabs ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #494f57;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .right .tabs ul li.active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #494f57;
}

.wrapper .right .register,
.wrapper .right .login{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .right .input_field{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrapper .right .input_field .input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #ecebeb;
}

.wrapper .right .btn{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #313840;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper .right .btn a{
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.logo2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Modal.js

```
//Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var modal_container  = document.getElementById("modalContainer")
modal_container.style.display = "none";


window.onclick = function (event) {
  console.log(event.target)
  if(event.target.id == "myBtn") {
    modal_container.style.display = "flex"
  }
  else if (modal !== event.target && !modal.contains(event.target)) {
    modal_container.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how it is looking [image]

This is how it looks inside my other file (that I did not use bootstrap)

[image]

Comment: why use `window.onclick`? why not use `document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("mouseup",function (event) { // code })`??

Comment: That worked man, now I get this error, where the modal displays but not the css, any guesses?

Comment: looking at your picture, the css is working. Some of the text is green and the modal text is gray. Maybe recheck your classes, and if nothings wrong, recode your CSS? You did make it `display: flex;`, maybe it was meant to be `display: block;`?

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy I changed the display to block but it still didn't work. It is getting the green from the general css, not the specific one for the modal.

Comment: hm did you include the modal css in your page? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/stylesheet.css">`

Comment: I am importing the css yes, I am adding this on top of the website. I am copying this modal from another website I have. But that website was made with html5/css3, this one I am using bootstrap and am trying to convert that modal to here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224059/discussion-between-tomas-mota-and-mr-pizzaguy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your button (to open the modal), you need to *connect* the button to the modal.

The bootstrap4 way to do this is to use attributes on the button. In your case, try:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

You should not need the modal.js file at all.

#### Reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: Ok, I changed that, but everything is unformatted, any guesses on that?

Comment: I have a hero section, then a main div, that englobes all of the other sections. I want that modal to stay hidden and on button click open.

Comment: Are you including the Bootstrap libraries correctly? Take another look at the Bootstrap4 modal example [on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp) and compare with yours.

Comment: Yes, that is how the Bootstrap modals should work - just follow the examples on W3Schools

Comment: Could you please take a look at the 2 images I just added please.

Comment: It can be pretty tedious to use the Bootstrap components because you must do it exactly right. For example, you cannot put the Bootstrap scaffolding into another div structure - they must be pretty much exactly like the template, with the body as the parent div.  HOWEVER, it is very easy to create your own modal - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796636)

Comment: Yes I understand and have followed a tutorial on how to create a modal with bootstrap, but I want to add the one I already have, but that one was made with html and css. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: In the [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp), notice that the modal has 3 parts: the header, the body and the footer. Everything inside your `<div id="myModal">` div (but not that top-level div) should go inside the Bootstrap modal body `<div class="modal-body">`. Here is what I suggest: remove your modal from the page and add an empty Bootstrap modal. Make it display. Then, add your own modal's content INTO the body part of the Bootstrap modal. I promise you, you'll have it finished in ten minutes.

Comment: Of course, once you have the modal displaying your content, you WILL need to fix your CSS (to allow for the classes, IDs, etc being inside the Bootstrap modal div structure). The first few will take some thinking, but after that it will go very fast. DevTools is your friend - if you don't know DevTools very well, watch some YouTube videos. DevTools is the best way to figure out the css, and it will save you TONS of time.

Comment: thank you man. I will look in to it and let you know how it went. Thank you for wasting your time with this. Have an amazing day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224069/discussion-between-tomas-mota-and-cssyphus).

Comment: Tomas, you have two choices: either do not use the Bootstrap modal (did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796636)? Here is a [Very Simple jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/07bvb5Lz/) of a self-rolled modal. It is Very simple - play with it. Study it.) Or, use the Bootstrap modal and remove your modal entirely from your page. Add in a super-basic Bootstrap modal and make it appear/disappear. If you haven't done this part, you will have trouble. Only THEN add your modal content into the BS4 modal body. Do you see your content? Finally: format your content. Please advise success.

Comment: Hey man, I have added the super basic modal and it does open and close. I just don't know how to add the animations mine has. Due to bootstrap being different from regular html...

Comment: (1) Don't *fight* Bootstrap - do not change the basic Bootstrap animations ***for the modal itself***.  If there are other animations that take place within the body of the modal (i.e. inside your form tags), then that's just getting the css (I assume) to work inside a Bootstrap modal div structure. You simply ***must*** use DevTools to figure that out because Bootstrap relocates the modal + content elsewhere in the DOM. It's still basic HTML/css/js, it's just been moved - so your css needs to know what to style and where.  If this doesn't answer your question, please open another question.

Comment: Why open another question: SO is not designed to facilitate conversation like this. As you add more information in chat, I am the only person (probably) who is following/answering. With a new question, dozens of people will read it within the first few minutes. You will get faster/better answers without delay. ALSO, StackOverflow is a question/answer game that works by questions, upvotes and checkmarks. Upvotes and checkmarks cost you nothing, so be generous (no reason not to). Sticking with the same question is usually much slower than asking several rapid-fire sequential questions.

Comment: But remember to choose a best answer (checkmark) to close the current question before opening the next *(or you could be downvoted for asking the same question multiple times - that is okay if the prev ques was closed, but not okay if you have one open)*. And upvoting encourages answerers to keep an eye out for your future questions.

Comment: Thank you man, I have added the upvote and check mark, and will add a new question. 
 Have a nice day.

Comment: When you add your new question, please post a comment in this thread and I will also take a look as soon as I am able.